# Angular disable input if checkbox is checked

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have one input and one checkbox and I want to disable the input if checkbox is checked. Any suggestions?

```html
<input formControlName="checkbox" type="checkbox">
<input formControlName="input" type="number">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular reactive forms disable input when checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369523/angular-reactive-forms-disable-input-when-checkbox-checked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reactive forms `valueChanges` observable on your checkbox control to achieve this.

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   // Your form
   form:FormGroup = this.fb.group({checkbox: false, input: ''});
   
   constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){}

   ngOnInit() {
      // Subscribe to value changes - this will trigger whenever the value of your checkbox is changed (through click, or programmatically)
      this.form.get('checkbox').valueChanges
         .subscribe(value => {
            if (value) {
               // disable the input when new value is true
               this.form.get('input').disable();
            } else {
               // (re-)enable the input when new value is false
               this.form.get('input').enable();
            }
         })
   }
}
```