# how to set default input value in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm Updating input value using a service. Value updates and it shows in input, but when I try to take value from form group it returns "". I want to get the updated value. it doesn't return updated value unless I edit input field manually.

component.html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input matInput formControlName="fname"  [value]="userData['f_name']">
</mat-form-field>

<button (click)="updateUserInfo()" mat-button color="primary">Save</button>
```

component.ts

```
 private userData = {};
 private UserDataForm : FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
   this.UserDataForm = this.fb.group({
          fname: ['',[
          Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(5)
          ]]
        }
}

updateUserInfo(){
    console.log(this.UserDataForm.value);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set reactive form after data loaded (async) - Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686147/set-reactive-form-after-data-loaded-async-angular-5)

Comment: Is f_name a typo for fname in `[value]="userData['f_name']"`?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your form, not the input value.

`this.UserDataForm.get('fname').setValue(// result of your service)`